# what is the difference between value and invalue statements in SAS?

Tags: sas

i am studying for the SAS base exam, i come from medical background. I intend to learn SAS clinical. 
what is the difference between invalue and value statements ?

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473466.htm
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473472.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VALUE statement in PROC FORMAT is used to define a FORMAT.  The INVALUE statement is used to define an INFORMAT.

In SAS you use a FORMAT to convert values into text and an INFORMAT to convert text into values.  You can use a FORMAT with the PUT statement or the PUT(), PUTN() or PUTC() functions. You can attach a format to a variable using a FORMAT statement.  You can use an INFORMAT with the INPUT statement or the INPUT(), INPUTN() or INPUTC() functions. You can attach an informat to a variable using the INFORMAT statement.